# How to apply funtion to single Column of large dataset using Dask?

Tags: python, dask, logarithm

If apply funtion to calculate logaritm at single column of large dataset using Dask, How can I do that?

```
df_train.apply(lambda x: np.log1p(x), axis=1 , meta={'column_name':'float32'}).compute()
```

The dataset is very large (125 Millions of rows), How can I do that?

Comment: How about `df_train.float32.map(np.log1p)`?

Answer (score 5):

You have a few options:

#### Use dask.array functions

Just like how your pandas dataframe can use numpy functions

```
import numpy as np
result = np.log1p(df.x)
```

Dask dataframes can use dask array functions

```
import dask.array as da
result = da.log1p(df.x)
```

#### Map Partitions

But maybe no such dask.array function exists for your particular function.  You can always use [map_partitions](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions), to apply any function that you would normally do on pandas dataframes across all of the pandas dataframes that make up your dask dataframe

**Pandas**

```
result = f(df.x)
```

**Dask DataFrame**

```
result = df.x.map_partitions(f)
```

#### Map

You can always use the `map` or `apply(axis=0)` methods, but just like in Pandas these are usually very bad for performance.

Comment: Thanks, So to make the calculations it's just: result = df_train.unit_sales.map_partitions(np.log1p).compute() ?

Comment: Yes, or `da.log1p(df_train.unit_sales)`, as in the first example above

Comment: When I run with .compute() my pc is freezing again, It is because I trying to calculate for the entire dataset of 125 Millions of rows?

Comment: That comment doesn't seem related to this question.  I recommend that you ask on the other question you recently asked, which seems more related. You might also consider editing your original question to include more details like "how do I check to see if it's safe to call compute" rather than engaging in a conversation in the comments.